# How to configure VM to display graphics effectively?

Tags: 20.04, graphics, virtualbox, video

I have a laptop (Ryzen 5-4500/8GB/no GPU). I recently installed Ubuntu on my VirtualBox (rather standard installation, fullscreen settings applied). There is a problem with my setup; I have issues running graphical applications (VLC, OBS, Blender) and YouTube. VLC is causing my VM to use 100% of it's allocated resources, OBS and online screen recorders videos are laggy. YouTube videos are buffering and the VM is using way too much resources. Blender is impossible to use. Have you got any ideas what may be causing this problem?

VM settings:

[image: VM settings]